# how can i draw and give motional property in cube?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How to rotate cube? without silverlight and flash? is it javascript? how can i do with ajax+C#? 
http://library.wolfram.com/explorations/webUnrisk/CheckCap.jsp

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is a Java applet.

HTML 5 has some impressive capabilities that don't require Java/Silverlight/Flash.

For example, see [this demo](http://gyu.que.jp/jscloth/touch.html).

Comment: Can i do that with Ajax? or javascript: js3d

Comment: I believe the demo is 100% HTML5 and JavaScript.

Comment: AJAX is only a method for exchanging data asynchronously between browser and server.

Answer (score 1):

It is <del>[JavaFX](http://javafx.com/).</del>

Sorry, @dtb is correct. it is java applet not javafx.

Sure you can do it with C# + Silverlight or ActionScript + Flash.

There is an interesting Silverlight & Flash sample to rotate cube on [ShineDraw's blog](http://www.shinedraw.com/animation-effect/flash-vs-silverlight-rotating-cube/)

Comment: Can i do that with Ajax? or javascript: js3d

Comment: AJAX is only a method for exchanging data asynchronously between browser and server.

Comment: Sure you can do it with javascript. Please check @dtb's answer, it uses HTML5 and javascript.